# Time Critical Handler Loop Impacted by Garbage Collection

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I am building an Android application that interfaces with the DJI SDK to operate their drones. To control the flight of a drone, I need to send my control commands between 5Hz-25Hz. I am using a runnable inside a loop to send my data, but I have noticed that occasionally subsequent iterations of the runnable are delayed up to 800ms, which causes the drone to stop moving.

I have managed to identify the app's garbage collection process as the culprit behind these delays, but I don't have the knowledge of how to mitigate this to ensure my loop is never delayed by it, as it is flight critical. I can replicate this by forcing a GC event in Android Studio's profiler.

This is the relevant code, the app currently only contains this logic while I am testing.

```java
long delay = 200;

HandlerThread vsThread = new HandlerThread("VirtualStickHandler", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
vsThread.start();
virtualStickDataHandler = new Handler(vsThread.getLooper());

virtualStickDataHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    mFlightController.sendVirtualStickFlightControlData(new FlightControlData(
        -.3f,
        0f,
        0f,
        0f
    ), null);
    virtualStickDataHandler.postDelayed(this, delay);
  }
}, delay);
```

Unfortunately my knowledge of Android threads and GC is lacking, so any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling with this issue for days now.

Comment: I would start with `FlightControlData` value caching  as you can't prevent from "GC stop"

Comment: Would that be leaking memory, having it created each time in the loop like that?

Comment: but you have the same value in every post (for now) so if you create final `FlightControlData` outside Runnable callback then it wont be created at every callback so it will takes longer before GC will collect

Comment: That makes sense, I've created `FlightControlData` outside of the runnable, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to improve things. Does GC run on each thread separately? I basically need to ensure it never impacts by runnable

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrLEoIsMIAc ... I'm pretty sure that you CAN'T ...

Comment: Search for Object Pool Pattern.